# elasticsearch categorize_text aggregation sorting with sub top_hits aggregation

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have the following aggregation. But want I want is that the buckets inside the topClassificationGroup are also sorted with the same sort as the topHits.
So the bucket containing the "best" top_hit should be first inside the classification aggregation.

```
"aggs": {
    "classification": {
        "categorize_text": {
            "field": "classification"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "max_score_inner": {
                "max": {
                    "script": {
                        "lang": "expression",
                        "source": "_score"
                    }
                }
            },
            "topClassificationGroup": {
                "categorize_text": {
                    "field": "subClassification",
                    "size": 3
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "topSubClassificationGroup": {
                        "top_hits": {
                            "size": 3,
                            "track_scores": true,
                            "sort": [
                                {
                                    "orderCount2": "desc"
                                },
                                {
                                    "bestOverall.raw": "desc"
                                },
                                {
                                    "bestOverallC.raw": "desc"
                                },
                                {
                                    "orderCount": "desc"
                                },
                                "_score"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use aggregations together with bucket_sort for some fields. But I am wondering if there is an easier solution. Also for the keyword fields may does not work and I don't know how.

```
"aggs": {
    "classification": {
        "categorize_text": {
            "field": "classification"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "max_score_inner": {
                "max": {
                    "script": {
                        "lang": "expression",
                        "source": "_score"
                    }
                }
            },
            "topClassificationGroup": {
                "categorize_text": {
                    "field": "subClassification",
                    "size": 3
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "max_order_count_2": {
                        "max": {
                            "field": "orderCount2"
                        }
                    },
                    "max_order_count": {
                        "max": {
                            "field": "orderCount"
                        }
                    },
                    "max_score": {
                        "max": {
                            "script": {
                                "lang": "expression",
                                "source": "_score"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "topSubClassificationGroup": {
                        "top_hits": {
                            "size": 3,
                            "track_scores": true,
                            "sort": [
                                {
                                    "orderCount2": "desc"
                                },
                                {
                                    "bestOverall.raw": "desc"
                                },
                                {
                                    "bestOverallC.raw": "desc"
                                },
                                {
                                    "orderCount": "desc"
                                },
                                "_score"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "sort_bucket": {
                        "bucket_sort": {
                            "sort": [
                                { "max_order_count_2": { "order": "desc" } },
                                { "max_order_count": { "order": "desc" } },
                                { "max_score": { "order": "desc" } }
                            ],
                            "gap_policy": "insert_zeros"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```